# Finding matches in two strings and marking those matches. Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find matches between two strings of the same length and I'm using the following code.

```
import operator

seq1 = input("Type the first sequence: ")
seq2 = input("Type the second sequence: ")

if len(seq1) != len(seq2):
    print("Sequences must be of the same length")

else:
    for i in range(len(seq1)):
        if (seq1[i] == seq2[i]):
            print ("There are", sum(map(operator.eq, seq1, seq2)), "matches:"+"\n", seq1+"\n", seq2+"\n", "*"*sum(map(operator.eq, seq1, seq2)))
```

The problem is that I want to put the "*" in the matched positions and I don't know how to indicate those positions. 
Another problem is that when I want to print the results, they are repeated once for every match. I can show you an example:

```
Type the first sequence: ATCGA
Type the second sequence: AACCA
There are 3 matches:
 ATCGA
 AACCA
 ***
There are 3 matches:
 ATCGA
 AACCA
 ***
There are 3 matches:
 ATCGA
 AACCA
 ***
```

And what I really want is the following:

```
Type the first sequence: ATCGA
Type the second sequence: AACCA
There are 3 matches:
 ATCGA
 AACCA
 * * *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are mixing here some concepts. You are making a loop and inside the loop you make a `map`. You only need one.

Suppose you want to find the positions of the matching elements:

```
[i for i in map(operator.eq, seq1, seq2)]
```

and

```
matches = [None] * len(seq1)
for i in range(len(seq1)):
    if (seq1[i] == seq2[i]):
        matches[i] = True
    else:
        matches[i] = False
```

are completly equivalent.

So to generate a result like you want you could alter for example the second one:

```
seq1 = 'ATCGA'
seq2 = 'AACCA'

matches = [None] * len(seq1)
for i in range(len(seq1)):
    if (seq1[i] == seq2[i]):
        matches[i] = '*'
    else:
        matches[i] = ' '
```

or as alternative with map:

```
matches = ['*' if i else ' ' for i in map(operator.eq, seq1, seq2)]
```

and then convert them to your output:

```
print(seq1)
print(seq2)
print(''.join(matches))
```

Comment: You would still need to check the lengths of the strings.

Comment: I don't need it since I'm hardcoding values. If he wants to use this concept with input he should compare those strings (but since he already does it and it works) I left it out because it makes the answer longer and doesn't help understanding it.

Comment: Yes, just using the same previous lines of my code it works perfecly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator expression and join it to return a string:

```
str1 = 'ATCGA'
str2 = 'AACCA'

if len(seq1) != len(seq2):
    print("Sequences must be of the same length")

else:

    matches = ''.join('*' if i==j else ' ' for i, j in zip(str1, str2))
    print("There are %d matches" % matches.count("*"))
    print(str1)
    print(str2)
    print(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
seq1 = input("Type the first sequence: ")
seq2 = input("Type the second sequence: ")
if len(seq1) != len(seq2):
    print("Sequences must be of the same length")
else:
    asterisk_string = "".join("*" if seq1[i] == seq2[i] else " " for i in range(len(seq1)))
    print("%d matches" % asterisk_string.count("*"))
    print(seq1)
    print(seq2)
    print(asterisk_string)
```

Example output:

```
Type the first sequence: ATCGA
Type the second sequence: AACCA
3 matches
ATCGA
AACCA
* * *
```